# detect keyboard key presses in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am completely new to programming and python so i wanted to know if there is any way to for the program to recognize when i have pressed a specific key and continue rather than using input() function where i have to press enter after i have entered my data.

I've tried using the getch() but the program just continues without waiting for a key to be pressed.

```
from msvcrt import getch
x=0
   while ord(getch() == 117):
      print("worked")
```

```
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but bool found
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote this expression:

> ord(getch() == 117)

Instead, use one of these (equivalent) expressions:

```
ord(getch()) == 117

getch() == chr(117)

getch() == 'u'
```